# How do I install luasql in Visual Studio Command Prompt 2015?

Tags: lua, love2d, luarocks, luasql

I am new in using luasql. I want to use it in Love2d. I already installed lua (Lua 5.3) and luarocks. I also installed MySQL using the msi installer. Now I think am ready to install luasql but I have the following error if I use the Visual studio command prompt:

[Unresolved External Symbol Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrmSS.png)
and
[Conflict with target Machine Type Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHwPR.png).

Does it have something to do with the msi installer? I am so confused. Do I need to install MySQL from source using Visual studio command prompt?

Comment: May be you use Lua 5.1 library but Lua 5.3 headers? You link against `lua51.lib`

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. I will try to install Lua 5.1. Do I need to install MySQL from source or just use the MSI?

Comment: You just need use Lua headers and libs for same version